# Group words based on the value of the first column

Tags: perl

I want to group all the file contents based on the value of first column. It would be better if the output is in sorted form.

Input:

```
1 foo
2 bar
1 foobar
2 barbar
3 apple
4 banana
3 mango
5 orange
```

Expected output:

```
1 foo, foobar
2 bar, barbar
3 apple, mango
4 banana
5 orange
```

Comment: Could you clarify? Why would the expected output be `1 foo, foobar`? What happened to `2 bar`? Don't you want something like `1 foo, foobar\n 2 bar`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're looking for

```
perl -lane 'push @{$k{$F[0]}},$F[1]; 
            END{$"=", ";print "$_ @{$k{$_}}" for sort keys(%k)}' file
```

There's no reason to explicitly split the line, the `-a` flag already does it for you. It will split each input line into the `@F` array. So, here we create the `%k` hash whose keys are the 1st fields and whose values are the corresponding lists of 2nd fields. Then, at the end, we sort the hash keys, set the list separator (`$"`) to `,[space]` and print each key and its corresponding list of values.

Comment: nice, but the command which uses hash displays the output in different order.

Comment: small update. the contents of the file is like `1 foo` `\n` `2 bar` `\n` `1 foobar` `\n` `2 barbar` list goes long, i want the output to be `1 foo, foobar` `\n` `2 bar, barbar` . `\n` is line break not a literal `\n` symbol.

Comment: @AvinashRaj come on, you know better than that! Don't post updates in comments, edit your question! I thought you only wanted the `1` lines. Now you say you also want the `2`? As for the order, yes, the hash will change the order. If that is a problem, you should mention it in your question.

Comment: updated my question.

Answer (score 3):

Another `perl`:

```
$ perl -anle '
    push @{$h{$F[0]}}, $F[1];
    END {
        for (sort {$a <=> $b} keys %h) {
            print "$_ ", join(", ", @{$h{$_}});
        }
    }
' file
1 foo, foobar
2 bar, barbar
3 apple, mango
4 banana
5 orange
```

**Explanation**

- We create a hash `$h`, which has keys are value `$F[0]`. Each hash's value is a array reference. When processing each line, we add value of the second field `$F[1]` to array reference `push @{$h{$F[0]}}, $F[1]`.
- After processing all lines, we sort the keys of `$h` (`sort {$a <=> $b} keys %h`), join each array reference to a string (`join(", ", @{$h{$_}})`), print each key corresponding with the join string.

Comment: +1 , i think it would be more helpful if you add an explanation.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Updated explanation.