# Organising column and items based on corresponding value from different column

Tags: shell-script, perl

I have a large **[input.csv file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dugrws4icw4t8nk/input.csv?dl=0)** that has 2 columns: Category (column A) and Item (column B), each Item having that specific Category found on column A and one row higher than the group itself; ex: rows 3-10 are a group of items corresponding to category "colours" (A2), etc:

```
Column A    Column B
Category    Item
colours 
            red
            blue
            pink
            yellow
            brown
            gray
            white
            violet
trees   
            coconut
            weeking wilow
            ginkgo
            dragon tree
            camphor tree
animals 
            sea urchins
            box jelyfish
            insect
            dinosaur
            triceratops
            apatosaurus
```

I am trying to get an **[output.csv file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dfs00qtzmu0v38s/output.csv?dl=0)** that will look like this:

- first column becomes Item
- 2nd column becomes Category and for each Item that corresponds to a specific category, I will have that category on the 2nd column on each row basically copying the category corresponding to each item

[image: input.csv notes]

This is how output.csv file finally looks like:

```
Column A        Column B
Item            Category
red             colours
blue            colours
pink            colours
yellow          colours
brown           colours
gray            colours
white           colours
violet          colours
    
coconut         trees
weeking wilow   trees
ginkgo          trees
dragon tree     trees
camphor tree    trees
    
sea urchins     animals
box jelyfish    animals
insect          animals
dinosaur        animals
triceratops     animals
apatosaurus     animals
```

I was trying to use the advice [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163161/group-words-based-on-the-value-of-the-first-column) but without success :|

**Is there any way I can accomplish this with a Perl script for instance, or anything else you'd recommend that I can run from a terminal command on Linux?**

Comment: Post text, not pictures, so people have sth. to test code on.

Comment: thx a lot will do so

Comment: OK. Is that a `<TAB>` separated file, as it looks like?

Comment: @RudiC it is a comma separated CSV file

Comment: Hmmm - scrutinizing, even with a magnifying glass, I can't seem to find a comma in your input sample?

Comment: @RudiC check [here](https://i.imgur.com/5BkYArF.png) this is what I see when opening the input.csv file with Sublime Text, seeing commas delimiting the 2 columns; on line 3 as you can see the first column is empty, and there's a comma and then "red" on 2nd column

Comment: Do you really expect people in here to tinker with your samples until they fit your problem? Please provide a sample correctly representing your problem / situation.

Comment: @RudiC you are right, thank you, I will test my input file again and get back here with a proper sample, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's a `<TAB>` separated `.csv` file, try

```
awk -F"\t" '$1 {CAT = $1} $2 {print $2, CAT}' OFS="\t" file
Item    Category
red     colours
blue    colours
pink    colours
yellow  colours
brown   colours
gray    colours
white   colours
violet  colours
coconut trees
weeking wilow   trees
ginkgo  trees
dragon tree     trees
camphor tree    trees
sea urchins     animals
box jelyfish    animals
insect  animals
dinosaur        animals
triceratops     animals
apatosaurus     animals
```

If the first field `$1` is not empty, the category ist saved. If the second field `$2` is not empty, the field and saved category is printed.

Comment: thanks a lot @RudiC! I am trying to implement this but not being able to get same output like you mention: my file is comma delimited; I even tried with a Tab delimited CSV file but not getting any result; [this is what my input.csv file](https://i.imgur.com/bRWESOX.png) looks like when opening it in Notepad++ or Sublime Text, not sure if it is identical to your input file?

Comment: I tried this comman `awk -F"\t" '$1 {CAT = $1} $2 {print $2, CAT}' OFS="\t" input.csv` but in the folder where i tested it nothing happened, I even tried this `awk -F"\t" '$1 {CAT = $1} $2 {print $2, CAT}' OFS="\t" input.csv > output.csv` but still nothing happened

Comment: Well, garbage in, garbage out. No commas in input sample data, no working script. Try setting the field separators to comma.

Comment: thanks @RudiC I will try that, thanks!